Photoshop curves adjustment layer, off-line node automatically appears
In Photoshop, quite often when I place a curves adjustment layer, the node in the image (red arrow) appears automatically.
I have scoured YouTube and Adobe help and can't find any explanation.
Does anyone know what this is? Please see attached image.
[automatic curves node][1]

Hi and welcome to S.O. Your question is not about programming or scripting and so is likely to get closed. Other communities (such as the Photography Stack exchange may be better suited to your question

Thank you for your comment. I apologize for not knowing where to post my question. I'll consult Stack Exchange.
